# How does converting long long to int work?

Tags: c++, integer, type-conversion

For example I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long a = 2346436346346346;

    int b = a;
    //int b = static_cast<int>(a) //same result

    std::cout << a << "\n" << b;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

```
2346436346346346
1223261034
```

By what logic does `b` take that value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> By what logic does b take that value?

It is implementation-defined, in your case the value is truncated:

```
2346436346346346 in binary is:

0000000000001000 0101011000010010 0100100011101001 0111101101101010

1223261034 in binary is:
                                  0100100011101001 0111101101101010
```

Answer (score 9):

The result of an overflowing assignment to a signed integer type is implementation defined:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); **otherwise, the value is implementation-defined**.

(4.7 Clause 3 in N4140)

So you would have to ask whoever provides your implementation what they say the result will be, the C++ standard does not say anything in regards to that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard *4.7\p3 Integral conversions [conv.integral]* **(Emphasis Mine)**:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type; otherwise, **the value is
>   implementation-defined**